# Linked-list in c++

Tags: c++, linked-list, valgrind

I have a problem w ith linked lists in c++.
I have class looking like that:

```
class list {
    private: struct node {
        node * next;
        int val;
    };
    node * head;
    node * current;
    public: list();
    list(const list & l);
    list & operator = (const list & l);~list();
    void insert(int a);
    void goToHead();
    int getCurrentData();
    void advance();
    bool moreData();
};
```

I wont describe all functions in here, i'm sure they are working properly however there is declaration of operator = :

```
list & list::operator = (const list & l) {
    if ( & l == this) return *this;
    current = NULL;

    node * src, * * dst;
    head = ( * this).head;

    src = l.head;

    dst = & head;
    while (src) {
        if (!( * dst)) { * dst = new node;
        }
        ( * dst) - > val = src - > val;

        if (src == l.current) current = * dst;
        src = src - > next;

        dst = & (( * dst) - > next);
    }
    while (( * dst) != NULL) {
        node * t = ( * dst) - > next;
        delete * dst;
        ( * dst) = t;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

It has to copy values from one list to the other, add nodes or delete them if necessary.It works if lists are equal or if second one is longer( so it has to delete nodes).However when it should add some nodes then :

```
==4582== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4582==    at 0x8048C52: list::operator=(list const&) (list.cpp:103)
==4582==    by 0x804891B: main (testlist.cpp:38)
==4582==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==4582==    at 0x402B9B4: operator new(unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==4582==    by 0x8048BDE: list::operator=(list const&) (list.cpp:93)
==4582==    by 0x804891B: main (testlist.cpp:38)
```

I have no idea what is wrong with this declaration.Thanks for help.

Sorry if format was wrong, I'm having some chrome issues and that was the reason. Maybe there are examples however I have to use this one, I had a task to do it this way, I mean  I had code example and just had to finish it. I still have same problem :
line 93 is :

```
 * dst = new node;
```

And 103 is just last closing bracket

```
}
```

Again thanks for help.

Comment: Please format your code correctly. Nobody is going to read code that looks like output from `/dev/random`.

Comment: I'd say there's plenty of examples how to get linked lists right, no need to ask again ...

Comment: Could you please indicate which line is line 103 in your code?

Answer (score 0):

1. Please format your code and mark line 93 and 103
2. If line 93 is

   *dst=new node;

and 103

```
node *t=(*dst)->next;
```

you may want to sent dst->next to NULL (after you make the new) otherwise it points to uninitialized memory.

Comment: Yep it may cause problems in some situations, but not this time.It works pretty well even without this deleting so it has to be something else.